# YouTube enable/disable caption while starting the video(YouTube android integration)

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

In YouTube android integration, Is there is way to enable/disable caption (through code) while in video is staring/loading.

Thanks,

Comment: What did you do to achieve this? Show your code/efforts here.StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you have a problem with your code, please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube API supports captions.
Use `caption.list()` to retrieve a list of caption tracks that are associated with a specified video

To disable use

```
caption.delete()
```

Refer the official documentation of YouTube API:https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions

Also refer the sample code at:https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java